# Enlaces por anclas, modificar scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

Tengo un enlace por ancla que me lleva a un div en otra página del sitio. No me gusta como se ve la página porque queda muy pegado al margen superior. Me gustaría desplazar el div hacia abajo.

**¿Cómo puedo hacerlo por javascript?** He intentado esto, pero no me funciona

```
if(window.location.hash) {

    var hashT= window.location.hash;

    var pos = $('.team-work__article').offset().top;
    pos = pos + $('.team-work__article').outerHeight();

    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: pos
    },500);
}
```

Estos son los links

```
<article class="team">
   <a href="profesionales.html#team-1" class="team-vail">
      <div class="team-content">
         <h3 class="team__title">Dr. Antonio Gabriel</h3>
         <p class="team_excerpt">Odontólogo</p>
      </div>

      <img src="images/team_02.jpg" alt="Dr. Antonio Gabriel" class="team__img">
    </a>
 </article>

 <article class="team">
   <a href="profesionales.html#team-2" class="team-vail">
      <div class="team-content">
         <h3 class="team__title">Dra. Sara Machín</h3>
         <p class="team_excerpt">Odontóloga</p>
      </div>

      <img src="images/team_03.jpg" alt="Dra. Sara Machín" class="team__img">
    </a>
 </article>
```

Y este es el código hacia donde van los links

```
<article id="team-1" class="team-work__article">
    <div class="team__content">
       <h3>Dr. Jose Carzorla</h3>
       <ul>
          <li>Director médico</li>
          <li>Responsable sanitario</li>
          <li>Dr. en Medicina y Cirugía</li>
           <li>Dr. en Odontología</li>
       </ul>
    </div>

    <img src="images/team_01.jpg" alt="Dr. Jose Carzorla" class="team-work__img">
</article>

<article id="team-2" class="team-work__article reverse">
    <div class="team__content">
       <h3>Dr. Antonio Gabriel</h3>
       <ul>
          <li>Director médico</li>
          <li>Responsable sanitario</li>
          <li>Dr. en Medicina y Cirugía</li>
          <li>Odontólogo - Ortodoncista</li>
       </ul>
    </div>

    <img src="images/team_02.jpg" alt="Dr. Antonio Gabriel" class="team-work__img">
</article>
```

Comment: Hola @SilviaPena si deseas respuestas recuerda revisar [ask], detalla y aporta información necesaria a tu pregunta, además es importante realices el [tour] para que conozcas el funcionamiento básico del sitio.